# How to use the browser as the GUI for an offline application?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I want to be able to create an offline program that can use the browser as GUI. I'm not particularly good at GUI programming in general, and overall it seems that using HTML and CSS to structure a GUI would be the easiest.

- Cross browser method is preferred, but I will most likely use Google Chrome
- I need to be able to open an external program, possibly with command line arguments

Javascript seems like the best language for this, however as far as I know it isn't possible to launch programs with it.

This is on Windows 7.

Comment: I prefer [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/)

Comment: When you say offline... is the idea that the browser makes no requests  and that the whole 'site' is distributed as a set of static files? Or do you mean you can run a little mini-server (like Node) locally that can serve requests?

Comment: You might want to look into [Node Webkit](http://nwjs.io/).

Answer (score 0):

That's a good idea and is done by a several popular softwares.

The best way is to make your offline program run a web server that the browser will be able to access.

ie: Your program starts a web server on `localhost:5555` and then you'll be able to request `http://localhost:5555/users` in Javascript, from your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be using a UI framework like AngularJS + local storage. I'm working on an app right now that will be used online (connected to the web), online locally (connected to a local server that is *not* connected to the web), and offline.

You could build a single-page web app and let Angular manage all the "urls".